# Prove $1-\cos x \geq x^2/\pi$, where $x \in [0, \pi/2]$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Prove $1-\cos x \geq  x^2/\pi$, where $x \in [0, \pi/2]$.

I tried Taylor's expansion, so
$$1-\cos x=\dfrac{x^2}{2}-\dfrac{x^4}{4}+...\leq \dfrac{x^2}{2}$$

Don't know how to process further... Any help? Thank you~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $\sin(t)$ is a concave function on the interval $I=\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$,

$$\forall x\in I,\qquad \color{red}{1-\cos(x)}=\int_{0}^{x}\sin(t)\,dt \color{red}{\geq} \int_{0}^{x}\frac{2t}{\pi}\,dt = \color{red}{\frac{x^2}{\pi}}.$$

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Why there are so many down voters? I think this solution is right.

Comment: Some people love to downvote me.

Comment: @NanLi AFAIK, there was only one downvote. But yes, the solution is correct.

Comment: +1. To compensate the DV's. A straightforward proof.

Answer (score 1):

*General comment:* Taylor expansions are unlikely to help you much to proven inequality on such interval, as they are inherently *local*: they will tell you how a function behaves on some arbitrarily small interval around some point of interest (usually zero), not more. Taylor series might help if the coefficients have always the same sign, but that's a different thing.)
*(There may be some specific cases which can be a counterexample, and I'd be happy to know more about them in the comments; but that's at least a good rule of thumb.)*

---

You can consider the function $f\colon(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 1-\cos x - \frac{x^2}{\pi}$.

Why? [Looking at a plot](https://goo.gl/UCuHGh), we can hope to show $f$ is increasing, which will give us what we want as $f(0)= 0$. And indeed, after computing the derivative we obtain that for $x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$,
$$
f'(x) = \sin x - \frac{2}{\pi}x
$$
Now, you can invoke (or prove, it is not hard and a good exercise — use concavity of $\sin$) the standard inequality
$$
\frac{2}{\pi}x\leq \sin x \leq x, \qquad x\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]
$$
to proceed and conclude.